# Tighter-spaced bulleted list should have ordinary line spacing to paragraphs/lines above and below

Tags: lists, memoir, line-spacing

To get tighter line spacing (my document's main spacing is 1.5-spacing, and I'm using `memoir`), I normally use a self-defined "tight list" (`tightlist` in the code below). This works well. However **I would like the list's spacing to the text above and below to be identical to the ordinary** (here: 1.5) **line spacing, that is I would like the list to behave like a vertical line-like atom with respect to the rest of the document.**

In the following document

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\OnehalfSpacing

\newenvironment{mytightlist}[3]{%
  % noticeably tighter than the memoir class's tightlist facilities
  \begin{Spacing}{1}%
  \begin{list}{#1}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#2}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{#3}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}%
  }%
}%
{\end{list}\end{Spacing}}


\begin{document}

Text. HHHHHHHHHH

Text. HHHHHHHHHH

\begin{mytightlist}{\(\bullet\)}{1.5em}{0.5em}
\item Text. HHHHHHHHHH
\item Text. HHHHHHHHHH
\end{mytightlist}

Text. HHHHHHHHHH

Text. HHHHHHHHHH

\end{document}
```

the spacing within line pairs 2/3 and 4/5 is *slightly* less than the intended spacing, namely that found within line pairs 1/2 and 5/6. Why? How can one fix this?

Btw, I don't care about whether a list "belongs" to a paragraph around it: for me, such spacing should be uniform. ("LaTeX goes to a lot of effort to distinguish in-paragraph lists from end- or start-of-paragraph lists"; [comment (quoted approximately) by David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94831/keeping-the-last-line-of-one-paragraph-with-the-first-line-of-the-next-paragraph#comment203048_94831))

Using [the `MySpacing` environment from this answer to a related question about spacing around blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99503/14996) instead of `Spacing` doesn't do the trick in this context.

Comment: i've processed your test file, extended it a bit to look at multi-line paragraphs, printed it out, and measured carefully.  i don't see any difference in the interline or inter-paragraph spacing *except within the list block*.  this may be a version difference; i'm still working with (the original) tex live 2012 and can supply version numbers if desired.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for testing! In addition to compiling it on my present machine (`pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)`), I've pasted the code into the [LaTeX-Online-Compiler V0.2](http://latex.informatik.uni-halle.de/latex-online/latex.php) of the Martin-Luther-Universität Halle-Wittenberg. The compiler there uses `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)`. I need to look at it at a large magnification level (1600% will do) to notice that lines 2&3 are about 7% closer than lines 1&2.

Comment: What about just changing the spacing _after_ opening the list?

Comment: @Tobias Good idea! This will cause an extraneous empty line, [like here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119904/14996), but this is easily fixed by writing `\end{Spacing}\vspace*{0pt}\end{list}` in the environment finalization code. Unfortunately the spacing between lines 4/5 will then be (visually/roughly at least) identical to that between lines 3/4.

Answer (score 3):

You're using different baselineskips and you don't take care of this aspect.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newlength{\tightlisttopsep}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \setlength{\tightlisttopsep}{-\baselineskip}
  \addtolength{\tightlisttopsep}{\fontchardp\font`j}% a descender
  \addtolength{\tightlisttopsep}{.15pt} % some overshoot
  \OnehalfSpacing
  \addtolength{\tightlisttopsep}{.7\baselineskip}% height of strut
  % Show the baselines
  \edef\myrule{\noexpand\smash{\vrule depth\the\baselineskip\kern-.4pt}}
}

\newenvironment{mytightlist}[3]{%
  % noticeably tighter than the memoir class's tightlist facilities
  \begin{Spacing}{1}%
  \begin{list}{#1}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{\tightlisttopsep}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#2}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{#3}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}%
  }%
}%
{\end{list}\end{Spacing}}


\begin{document}

1. HHHHHHHHH\myrule H

2. HHHHHHHHHH\myrule

\begin{mytightlist}{\(\bullet\)}{1.5em}{0.5em}
\item 3. HHHHHHHHHH
\item 4. \myrule HHHHHHHHHH
\end{mytightlist}

5. HHHHHHHHHH

6. HHHHHHHHHH

\end{document}
```

This is without hope if the `mytightlist` is used when a different font size is in force, because the settings are made just for the standard size.

The result is surely poor typography, in my opinion.

[image]

Comment: How does the ideal typographic relationship of bulleted lists with paragraphs above and below look like, in your opinion? Any opinions, rambling, and detours are appreciated. Perhaps you could give an opinion for both a "uniform spacing throughout" case and a "paragraphs are required to be 1.5-spaced" case.

Comment: @LoverofStructure Typography ≠ 1.5 spacing. And this kind of tight spacing in a sea of wide spacing is horrible. Give it more room before and below, rather than the same as normal interline spacing.

Comment: Well, I'm definitely with you on that (as I say elsewhere), though I must admit that I now find that text with a lot of in-paragraph math can benefit from >1-spacing (not "1.5-spacing" though, which I think translates to something like a `1.3` spacing parameter in `memoir`). In any case, (La)TeX does a certain thing when it comes to lists in between paragraph text, and I find its default spacing too wide (this is a very strong opinion on mine). So I really am interested in what your opinion on this general situation is, assuming something like single-spacing for the main body.

Comment: @LoverofStructure 10/15.6 is definitely too spaced. Depending on the font, 10/13 or 10/13.5 might do; 10/14 is already too much, I believe.

Comment: And how would you embed lists in paragraph text? I'm asking about the spacing just before and after the list and the line-spacing within the list (which I think should be identical or *might* even be tighter)?

Comment: @LoverofStructure `\topsep=.5\baselineskip`, for instance; they *must* be visually distinct, particularly if their baselineskip is reduced. But that format of yours is flawed to begin with.

Comment: Could you explain the `.15pt` and `.7\baselineskip` in your code?

Comment: @LoverofStructure The latter is the height of the strut with the increased baselineskip; the former is an eye computed correction for overshoot.

Comment: But how did you compute `.7`? (Note: Above I wrote that "1.5"-spacing uses a `1.3` value somewhere in `memoir`, but I think that's not right, actually.) And what is the overshoot of `.15pt` for and where does it come from (the strut not matching the nominal/declared dimensions in the font?)?

Answer (score 2):

As to why it exists, I can't say.  As to how to fix it (at least for your MWE), I add a symmetric `\vspace` of `.049\baselineskip` before and after the environment.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\def\vertoffset{.049\baselineskip}

\OnehalfSpacing

\newenvironment{mytightlist}[3]{%
  % noticeably tighter than the memoir class's tightlist facilities
  \begin{Spacing}{1}%
  \begin{list}{#1}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#2}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{#3}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}%
    \vspace{\vertoffset}%
  }%
}%
{\end{list}\vspace{\vertoffset}\end{Spacing}}


\begin{document}

Text. HHHHHHHHHH

Text. HHHHHHHHHH

\begin{mytightlist}{\(\bullet\)}{1.5em}{0.5em}
\item Text. HHHHHHHHHH
\item Text. HHHHHHHHHH
\end{mytightlist}

Text. HHHHHHHHHH

Text. HHHHHHHHHH

\end{document}
```

Comment: I initially thought it might have something to do with the height of the `\strutbox`, but I could find no obvious connection.  In the end, I brute forced it.  Perhaps `.049\baselineskip` which is 0.73494pt for this case, will jog someone's memory on a "lost" dimension.

Comment: Did you determine the value `0.049\baselineskip` manually (by trial/error/adjustment)?

Comment: @LoverofStructure: Yes, at 2600% magnification

Comment: Interesting how adding vertical space *symmetrically* seems to work. I'm also wondering what a more generally applicable solution is (one that is proven to work everywhere). Bounty well deserved! I'll reopen a larger one now.

Comment: @LoverofStructure  Thanks.  I agree that the symmetrical nature of the "fix" just screams something important.  But I just can't tell you what.

Comment: A similarly weird situation is described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119904/14996); no one has so far determined what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

Reading your question I am not sure if you want also a 1.5 **within** the list environment. If this matter, then the fix of Steven is not complete  since spacing between normal text lines items is`15pt` whereas between items is only  `12pt`.

My attempt to fix both problems is simply change two of the   `\setlenght`s of your macro to:

```
\setlength{\topsep}{.7pt}% 
\setlength{\itemsep}{3pt}%
```

To see how good is this fix, an easy test is that `\vspace{-15pt}` after some line or item  must produce a perfect overlapping with the next line or item. In the next image I used some `\phantom` spaces in overlapping lines and red color in the whole overlapped line-item to check it better. At 400% this is the output:

[image: MWE]

The source code to test yourself:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\OnehalfSpacing

\newenvironment{mytightlist}[3]{%
  % noticeably tighter than the memoir class's tightlist facilities
  \begin{Spacing}{1}%
  \begin{list}{#1}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{.7pt}% .1ex
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{3pt}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#2}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{#3}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}%
  }%
}%
{\end{list}\end{Spacing}}


\begin{document}


Text. {\color{red}HHHHHHHHHH (1-2 li\vspace{-15pt}}

Text. HHHHHHHHHH \phantom{(1-2 li}ne)

Text. HHHHHHHHHH (3 line)

Text. {\color{red}HHHHHHHHHH (4-1 line \vspace{-15pt}}

\begin{mytightlist}{\(\bullet\)}{1.5em}{.5em}
\item Text. HHHHHHHHHH  \phantom{(4-1 line}item) 
\item Text. HHHHHHHHHH (2 item) 
\item {\color{red}Text. HHHHHHHHHH (3-4 it}\vspace{-15pt}
\item Text. HHHHHHHHHH \phantom{(3-4 it}em) 
\item Text. HHHHHHHHHH (5 item)
\item {\color{red}Text. HHHHHHHHHH (6-1 item\vspace{-15pt}}
\end{mytightlist}

Text. HHHHHHHHHH \phantom{(6-5 item}line)

Text. HHHHHHHHHH (6 line)

Text. {\color{red}HHHHHHHHHH (7-8 li\vspace{-15pt}}

Text. HHHHHHHHHH \phantom{(7-8 li}ne)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Within the list I want single spacing, but thanks for your contribution and approach!