# Extraneous empty line within memoir's list environment (for very tight lists) if used with memoir's Spacing environment (for single-spacing)

Tags: spacing, lists, memoir

In order to typeset lists with very tight interline spacing, I normally define my own `tightlist` using `memoir`'s `list` environment.

Even though my definition (see shortly) (1) ensures that all vertical spacing parameters are zero and (2) uses the `Spacing` environment to ensure single-spacing (in a 1.5-or-wider spacing environment), I strangely get an extraneous empty line after a nested `tightlist`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newenvironment{mytightlist}[3]{%
  \begin{Spacing}{1}%
  \begin{list}{#1}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#2}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{#3}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}%
  }%
}%
{\end{list}\end{Spacing}}


\begin{document}

Text.

\begin{mytightlist}{\(\bullet\)}{1.5em}{0.5em}
\item Text.
  \begin{mytightlist}{\(\circ\)}{1.5em}{0.5em}
  \item Text.
  \item Text.
  \end{mytightlist}% there is an empty line here that shouldn't be there
\item Text.
\end{mytightlist}

Text.

\begin{mytightlist}{\(\bullet\)}{1.5em}{0.5em}
\item Text.
  \begin{mytightlist}{\(\circ\)}{1.5em}{0.5em}
  \item Text.
  \item Text.
  \end{mytightlist}\vspace{0pt}% this magically prevents the empty line from occurring
\item Text.
\end{mytightlist}

Text.

\end{document}
```

**Issuing `\vspace{0pt}` after the nested `tightlist` eliminates the empty line, so that solves the problem, but why does this happen in the first place, and why does this solution work?** It seems like this behavior is caused by how the `Spacing` environment interacts with the `list` environment.

Comment: Why are you adding `Spacing` around it?

Comment: @daleif Good observation! To ensure single-spacing within wider-spaced environments. It looks like this is the fault of `Spacing`. Let me edit the question title to make this clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure WTF is going on. But I'm guessing that when it is used within a list some of the vertical spacing macros behave differently.

Comment: In any case it might be better to use `enumitem` for configuring lists anyway.

Comment: If you replace `\begin{Spacing}{1}` with `\setSpcaing{1}` and remove `\end{Spacing}` it seems to work ok in a double spaced situation. Tough it still leave space below.

Comment: @daleif Using `enumitem` is a good idea; I might also try `paralist`. I haven't yet used them with `memoir` because it seemed safer to customize its "native" `list` environment.

Comment: @daleif I think `memoir`'s `Spacing` environment is the preferred way and `\setSpacing` might be obsolesced by it. I think similar additional spacing below appeared with `memoir`'s `\SingleSpacing`, which is (if I remember correctly) why I am using `\begin{Spacing}{1}`...`\end{Spacing}` instead. But it's good that we are documenting these details here in this thread.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what it is you want to end up with. Say the document is double spaced and there is text before and after the list, show should it behave (double spaced docs are nasty)

Comment: @daleif Important question; my previous two questions [Tighter-spaced bulleted list should have ordinary line spacing to paragraphs/lines above and below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118184/14996) and [Changes in spacing (“Spacing” environment) for a block should not affect the line spacing of the block to the material above and below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96821/14996) are about that.

Comment: Pass cannot help you there

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `Spacing` to begin with. But if you do (and you shouldn't), issue `\begin{Spacing}` only when really necessary.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry} % just to fit the example in one page
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\iftightlist
\newenvironment{mytightlist}[3]{%
  \iftightlist
    \def\finishspacing{}%
  \else
    \begin{Spacing}{1}\def\finishspacing{\end{Spacing}}%
  \fi
  \tightlisttrue
  \begin{list}{#1}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#2}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{#3}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}%
  }%
}%
{\end{list}\finishspacing}


\begin{document}

\begin{Spacing}{1.5}

\lipsum*[2]

\begin{mytightlist}{\(\bullet\)}{1.5em}{0.5em}
\item \lipsum*[2]
  \begin{mytightlist}{\(\circ\)}{1.5em}{0.5em}
  \item \lipsum*[2]
  \item \lipsum*[2]
  \end{mytightlist}
\item \lipsum*[2]
\end{mytightlist}

\lipsum*[2]

\end{Spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the problem nesting? or what is it that goes wrong here?

Comment: @daleif I really don't know; I tried the easiest path of not issuing `\begin{Spacing}{1}` if already in a `mytightlist` environment and it worked.

Comment: Why should people not use `Spacing`?

Comment: @LoverofStructure Increasing the interline skip can be done, but only for small fractions of the font size; some fonts need more room because of their shapes. A line spread factor of 1.3 or more is just awful, leaving the words drowning in a sea of white space.

Comment: I am entirely with you. As you know, some institutions require "doublespacing" for submissions, which is awful indeed (and I don't like "1.5-spacing" either), so `Spacing` in my case is intended to revert the spacing to the normal spacing that you'd find in books whenever I can get away with it.